# How to asynchronously execute a function?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I am working on a vb.net application and I am struggling to get this function to run in parallel. This is a legacy application, I was told that it uses an event-based asynchronous pattern, but I do not exactly understand what that means for this problem.

There is a for loop that runs a function serially, but I would like to run it in parallel.

```vb
    Public Function Execute() As Boolean

        Dim ret As Boolean = True

        ' If output files are not specified, then they will be generated based on the study name
        If CancelExecution Then Return CancelCleanUp()

        If ValidateInputFiles() Then
            If CancelExecution Then Return CancelCleanUp()

            Select Case _Name
                Case "Main Single"
                    ' This is the for loop I would like to run in parallel
                    For Each cc As IOFile In _CCards
                        If ValidateOutputFiles(cc.FileName) Then
                            ret = RunModel(cc)
                            If CancelExecution Then Return CancelCleanUp()
                        Else
                            ret = False
                        End If
                    Next
                ' The other Cases are irrelevant 
            End Select
        Else
            ret = False
        End If

        Return ret
    End Function

    Private Function RunModel(cCard As IOFile) As Boolean

        Dim uFile As String
        Dim ret As Boolean = True

        If CancelExecution Then Return CancelCleanUp()

        ' create the uconfiguration file
        If _RunNumber > 0 Then
            uFile = MakeUFile(cCard, _InputFiles, _OutputFiles, _RunNumber)
        Else
            uFile = MakeUFile(cCard, _InputFiles, _OutputFiles)
        End If

        ' Input: was not part of the vb 6 IInputModel class, but added in this version
        ' Main: delete files mainmodel is about to create (even the optional files) (calls CleanUpSingleRun)
        ret = KillIOFiles(_OutputFiles)

        ' execute the application
        If File.Exists(uFile) Then

            Dim arg As String = """" & uFile & """"
            If _Name = "Main Single Sensitivity" Then
                ' 7/27/2105 add an argument for either single or production run - this is a single run module
                arg = arg & " SINGLE" & " " & "NOVIZ"
            End If

            ret = RunApplication(arg)
        Else
            Return False
        End If

        'execute? did it terminate properly?

        ' kill the ufile
        Try
            File.Delete(uFile)
            Dim cleanupFiles = Directory.GetFiles(_SensitivityFolder).Where(Function(e) e.Contains(".spw") Or Path.GetFileName(e).StartsWith("SIMU")).ToList()

            For Each fileToDelete As String In cleanupFiles
                File.Delete(fileToDelete)
            Next

            ' clean up temp combined files
            If CombinedFile <> "" Then System.IO.File.Delete(CombinedFile)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

        ret = VerifyOutputFiles(cCard.FileName)

        Return ret

    End Function
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: An example of a class that implements an event-based asynchronous pattern is `WebClient`. You can call `DownloadFile` and it will block until the file has downloaded or you can call `DownloadFileAsync` and it will return immediately and then the `DownloadFileCompleted` eventis raised when the file has downloaded. More recently, the `DownloadFileTaskAsync` method was added, which implements a task-based asynchroinous pattern, i.e. the method immediately returns a `Task` and that is used to determine the state of the download and when it completes.

Comment: If you have a `For Each` loop that you want to parallelise then the obvious solution is to use `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I was not aware that Parallel.ForEach was a thing, that sounds like that will solve my problem, I won't be able to test it until tomorrow though. Thanks for the input!